# Is it possible to run a password reset user flow, right after using sign in user flow in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In Azure B2C, I have a sign in user flow to sign in the user. Since they still don't have a password reset on first sign in, I used the following method.

1. The user has a custom attribute called 'IsUserNew'. This is used to
   check whether the user is new or not.
2. If the user is new, I wanna
   redirect the user to the B2C, with a password reset user flow.

The problem is, after sign in, the user is not redirecting to B2C. Is it because the user as already signed in with a user flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using Custom Policy and your extension attribute is defined as boolean and value is true on registration, if this is the case you can do following:

1. OrchestrationStep for Authentication.
2. OrchestrationStep for Read User Details, in the technical profile add "**extension_IsUserNew**" so that this attribute can be read from User.
3. Add below in the next OrchestrationStep. This will check the attribute and call the Password Technical Profile.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_IsUserNew</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>            
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>extension_IsUserNew</Value>
              <Value>True</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>            
          </Preconditions>        
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

4. Add Step to modify the "extension_IsUserNew" value or delete the attribute so that Password Reset will not ask in the next login.

In 1 Policy only you can handle the Password Reset in 1st login, no need to create separate policies.

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way to achieve this using an inbuilt policy?

Comment: No, you need custom policy for any custom logic.

Comment: Can you provide me the steps to modify the custom attribute? thanks in advance  @Rohit

Comment: If you are asking for to create custom attribute in B2C and how to use it, Please follow this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes